# What do [[ and ]] do in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

In vim (and vi) if I am in the command mode and I type `[[` it appears to go to the start of the the file, and if I type `]]` it appears to go to the end of the file. But I thought that `gg` and `G` were the start/end of file commands, so are `[[` and `]]` doing something different?

My guess is that `[[` and `]]` will go to the next instance of something, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `:help ]]`:

> `]]` [count] sections forward or to the next '{' in the
>               first column.

Further reading: `:help section`.

Pro tip: Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that I could use `:help`.

Answer (score 6):

I never found the default behavior of `[[` and `]]` useful UNTIL I saw this tip from `:help section`

```
If your '{' or '}' are not in the first column, and you would like to use "[["
and "]]" anyway, try these mappings:

   :map [[ ?{<CR>w99[{
   :map ][ /}<CR>b99]}
   :map ]] j0[[%/{<CR>
   :map [] k$][%?}<CR>
```

Comment: The Vim defaults are definitely [not that useful](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/50.html). These mappings are a great template for customizing them to be more useful, nice find.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK,

```
[[ : jump to function start
]] : jump to function end
```

EDIT: I also found a cheat sheet that defines:

```
(  [count] : sentences backward
)  [count] : sentences forward
{  [count] : paragraphs backward
}  [count] : paragraphs forward
]] [count] : sections forward or to the next '{' in the first column. When used after an operator, then the '}' in the first column.
][ [count] : sections forward or to the next '}' in the first column
[[ [count] : sections backward or to the previous '{' in the first column
]] [count] : sections backward or to the previous '}' in the first column
```

Comment: ]] doesn't jump to func end

Answer (score 3):

From `:help [[`,

```
[[          [count] sections backward or to the previous '{' in
            the first column.  |exclusive|
            Note that |exclusive-linewise| often applies.
```